# Significance of the similar color palette for Anna's winter dress and Elsa's coronation dress

Tags: costume, frozen

Color is often used intentionally in movies. I found it interesting that in *Frozen* the color palette for the winter dress that Anna bought in Oaken's store is similar to Elsa's coronation dress. I don't know why the producers of the movie decided to depart from what seems like Anna's standard green palette.

[image: Elsa coronation dress][image: Anna's winter dress]

Comment: Fashion follow royalty. Oaken is no fool, he knows what's good to sell.

Comment: @cde Oaken is a savvy businessman but he'd be incredible to produce a *winter outfit* that matches Elsa's coronation outfit within hours. Especially since this was his *only* set of winter clothes for sale. Oaken was clearly taken by surprise with the whole weather change or his winter section would be more robust.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is discussed in the "[Art of Frozen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1452117160)" book.

> [[Michael] Giaimo](http://www.hitfix.com/news/michael-giaimo-on-creating-the-3d-world-for-frozen) is an extremely analytical designer, and when he imagined the
> costumes for the characters, he applied rigorous aesthetic standards.
> "For Anna's travel outfit, I wanted something that would be really
> striking and bold, yet elegant," he begins. **"She's a princess, and
> that really blue skirt says royalty, as does the magenta cape. I
> thought those two colors would be really striking, because there's a
> rich saturation to both of them. But there's always a little bit of
> black on the characters: it helps anchor the saturation, so it doesn't
> float into the atmosphere."**

The warmer green palette was reserved for Anna as she grew and reflected her "sunny disposition". Obviously by the point in the film that she's changed clothes, her disposition is slightly more reserved.

[image: Young Anna in a yellow dress, young Anna in an olive dress, tween Anna in a dress with olive top and blue skirt.]

Caption:

> To reflect her sunny nature, Anna's color palette during her growing years is kept on the warm side. Grayed yellow greens, ochre, and olive dominate.

Comment: Anna's final costume is also in the green palette after Elsa melts the snow. So is the progression "sunny" to "slightly reserved" (but willing to declare Hans is her true love), back to "sunny"?

Comment: @Erik - That certainly seems to be the implication. When she's worried about her sister, her clothing becomes far more clasically "regal" in both design and palette. At the end she has largely returned to being the younger sister.

Comment: So green is "younger sister" mode and "classically regal" is protector/helper/equal mode?

Comment: @Erik - Yes, and note how rustic and understated her final outfit is in comparison to Elsa's "Ice Queen" dress. It's not hard to see which one is the support and which is the leader.

Answer (score 0):

I think they are equals, they both lead in different ways. Elsa even said the line about the bridge having two sides/daughters at the end!  Some people relate to Elsa (like me), and some relate to Anna.  It's a perfect balance and the last good thing in my opinion,  Disney did, though Jennifer Lee is who is to thank and the people who worked on the film and designs, not Disney.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).